# GAE Java Flexible env random INSTANCE being created

Tags: java, google-app-engine

app.yaml

runtime: java
manual_scaling:
instances: 1

Created an instance instance-1 from the console.
After deploying the app, google app engine created another instance gae-default-***..
When we shout down this instance, app stops working.

Just want to know will there be billing for 2 instances here and why this default instance is created automatically even when we create a named instance from the console and set manual scaling:1

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create instance/s for GAE. The GAE itself will provision an instance for you (as it actually does according to your description).

To avoid "double" billing, delete the instance you have manually created.

Comment: How come GAE decide the machine type of my instance ? If I have to customise the configuration of my instance then how it will be possible ?

Comment: @TechSupport you control the instance type via ```app.yaml``` file as following:
    
    resources:
     cpu: .5
     memory_gb: 1.3
     disk_size_gb: 10

According to these settings, GAE will setup an instance type for your app.